# Is there any faster way to delete all white space/tabs of a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the optimal way to remove all the spaces from a pandas data frame?
In SO I have found some suggestions as:

```
df = df.replace({'\s': ''}, regex=True)
```

or

```
df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
```

But since my data is too large, is taking too much time to compute.
for a small fraction of my dataset is taking 2mins. And my full dataset is (1Tb)

Is there any way to improve this? Parallelize? Better function? or just use another language?

Comment: probably a good use case for `Dask` or `Pyspark` you're dealing with strings, so it will always be sub optimal.

Comment: Clean up the data **before** they go into a dataframe